# Representing repeated measures with splines in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, spline

The dataset is repeated measures of tn (as % of peak tn) over days. I am trying to plot each individual patient with an overall smoothing/spline function.

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=day, y=tn))
p + geom_line(aes(colour=id)) + xlim(-3,3) +
   geom_smooth(method="lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x,5))
```

However, the `geom_smooth` function doesn’t go through 100% (although by definition all the records do, on the same day=0). Could anyone explain why, or explain how to represent my data better please?

```
id  day tn(%)
1   1   100
1   2   41
1   3   NA
2   -1  NA
2   0   100
2   -3  78
3   -2  1
3   -1  60
3   0   100
3   1   54
3   2   16
3   3   6
4   -2  66
4   -1  55
4   0   100
4   1   59
4   2   83
5   -2  2
5   -1  7
5   0   100
5   1   64
5   2   32
6   -2  0
6   -1  97
6   0   100
6   1   52
6   2   18
```

Comment: First off, you are missing your x variable in `aes(x=...`. Did you mean to assign x to `day`?

Comment: @sc_evans oops, yes edited with x=day, thanks